# Is it possible to use R's base::strsplit() without consuming pattern

Tags: r, regex, string

I  have a string that consists entirely of simple repeating patterns of a [:digit:]+[A-Z] for instance 12A432B4B.

I want to to use base::strsplit() to get:

```
[1] "12A" "432B" "4B"
```

I thought I could use lookahead to split by a LETTER and keep this pattern with `unlist(strsplit("12A432B4B", "(?<=.)(?=[A-Z])", perl = TRUE))` but as can be seen I get the split wrongly:

```
[1] "12"   "A432" "B4"   "B"
```

Cant get my mind around a pattern that works with this strsplit strategy? Explanations would be really appreciated.

**Bonus**:
I also failed to use back reference in `gsub` (e.g. - pattern not working `gsub("([[:digit:]]+[A-Z])+", "\\1", "12A432B4B"), and can you retrieve more than \\1 to \\9 groups, say if [:digit:]+[A-Z] repeats for more than 9 times  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use regex lookaround to split between an upper case letter and a digit

```
strsplit(str1, "(?<=[A-Z])(?=[0-9])", perl = TRUE)[[1]]
#[1] "12A"  "432B" "4B"
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "12A432B4B"
```

Comment: Damn! I still dont get it why it works - something along "split by A-Z and 0-9 but dont consume them" ?

Comment: @user3375672 It is checking for the boundary between a letter (uppercase) and digit

Answer (score 1):

The pattern mentioned in the post can be used as it is in `str_extract_all` :

```
str_extract_all(string, '[[:digit:]]+[A-Z]')[[1]]
#[1] "12A"  "432B" "4B"
```

Or in base R :

```
regmatches(string, gregexpr('[[:digit:]]+[A-Z]', string))[[1]]
```

where `string` is :

```
string <- '12A432B4B'
```